# Indexação no google TAG h1

Tags: html5, css3, google, seo

Bom dia.

Até onde vai meu conhecimento o google indexa o a tag h1, como eu faço o texto que quero indexar relacionado ao site está no meio de p mas gostaria que a tag  `<h1>` seguisse a formatação de fonte e tamanho do da tag p.

Tentei no css `h1 {display: none;}` /h1

Link do site como está hoje www.aguiasolar.com.br, na verdade vou eliminar as `<h1>` de hoje e colocar como h2 já testei ficou legal, ae no meio de um `p` vou selecionar uma parte do texto como `h1` só que quero que ele siga a formatação do paragrafo.

O problema é que meu site não aparece nas pesquisas, até paguei R$ 100,00 no adwords pra ver se melhorava não deu resultado.

Comment: Você conhece o schema.org? Dê uma olhada https://schema.org/docs/gs.html .

Comment: Dei uma olhada no seu site, coloque a mesma class da tag "p" nas tag "h", ficaria assim: <h1 class="lead"> seu texto </h1>, remova a tag <h7> pois no HTML é de h1 ao h6, segue o link da api html das tags headings https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Comment: Outra dica seria colocar seu site para rodar em seu servidor em protocolo HTPPS/SSL, hoje é requisito para estar no topo da pesquisa do Google.

Comment: Sobre o schema não entendi muito bem, mas coloquei o site como HTTPS/SSl, vou acompanhar ver se melhora no google.

Comment: Sobre h7 eu criei pq ela tem uma personalização no css, já usava as outras tag não sei se tem problema.

Comment: A questão do schema é algo mais avançado e bem poderoso para essa função, porém existe outras formas mais simples, o Hugocsl deu boas dicas, eu vi seu site rapidamente. Pesquise sobre SEO como ele disse e use os navegadores mais mordenos, as ferramentas incluidas neles, tipo no Google Chrome > ferramentas do desenvolvedor > Audits ... você pode fazer uma analise automática e ele te mostra muita coisa bacana... existem inúmeras ferramentas, boa sorte.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, acho que vc tem que para um pouquinho para ler sobre SEO e HTML, antes de sair mexendo nas coisas, é melhor fazer com calma e depois avaliar os resultados, tipo um teste A/B, do que ficar mexendo sem ter certeza do que está fazendo.... Vou sugerir que leia pelo menos os links que voi citar aqui, vão te ajudar muito, pois são conceitos básicos!

Primeiro, no **SERP** (Search Engine Result Page) o que tem mais peso é a tag `<title>` e nao a tag `<h1>`, o que o Google vai mostrar é o texto que está no `<titel>` dentro do seu `<head>`, leia mais sobre o SERP aqui: https://sitechecker.pro/pt/serp/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O outro texto que vai aparecer no SERP é a descrição da página, e isso é feito com a *meta tag Description*

```
<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
```

Vc pode ler mais sobre esse tipo de tag nessa docomentaçao da própria Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=pt-BR

Além disso existe uma série de boas práticas para construir sua tag Title e Description, como não colocar mais de 60 caracteres para o Title e mais de 160 para o Description, sugiro que leia esse artigo https://rockcontent.com/blog/tamanho-da-title-tag/

*OBS: Esses números costumam mudar, pois o Google costuma mudar o Layout do SERP deixando mais ou menos caracteres disponíveis, mantenha-se informado sobre essas mudanças...*

A dica do Schema.org é bem interessante, assim como estudar um pouco sobre Rich Snippets e Meta dados / Dados Estruturados, isso vai ajudar a melhorar ainda mais sua apresentação no SERP, ***mas não garantem em nada a sua melhora no rankeamento! Não vou entrar nesse assunto aqui, pois não é o foco.***

---

**Sobre o HTML**

Um `<h1>` no meio de um `<p>` não faz muito sentido, e nem é muito semântico... Como vc quer ter um título no meio do um parágrafo? Isso soa tao errado quanto de fato é. Um título é um elemento a parte e deve ser separado do parágrafo, o texto vem depois do título, e pode ser um H2 caso vc precise de um sub-título ou o P com o texto corrido mesmo. Vc ainda pode colocar o H1 e o P dentro de uma `<section>` para dizer que um é ligado diretamente ao outro.

Comment: Valeu as dicas, queria fazer isso, pq gostaria, que fosse indexado no google, referente ao paragrafo e não ao titulo do site, mas to estudando vendo que é melhor.

Comment: @CaioCésarRubo sem problemas, se vc ler pelo menos os links que eu postei ai, já vai te dar uma boa ideia das coisas. Depois se vc achar que a minha Resposta atende a sua Pergunta, lembre-se de marcar nesse icone `✔` abaixo das setinhas ao lado da minha resposta. Depois se aparecer outra resposta que vc julgue melhor vc pode mudar isso. Bons estudos e se tiver outra dúvida é só postar outra pergunta ou comentar aqui.