# Removi todas as TAGs de postagens do Wordpress, mas continua mostrando no Google

Tags: wordpress, google, seo

Fazendo manutenção de SEO de meu site, apaguei todas as TAGS cadastradas por muitas não serem mais válidas:

Link do Wordpress para edição das tags: `wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag`

No Yoast SEO, na aba "Taxionimias", na opção `Tags (post_tag)` marquei como "NÃO" a opção `Mostrar Tags nos resultados de pesquisa?`.

Mandei o sitemap.xml ao console do Google e até pedi para reindexar o site, mas continua mostrando as "Tags" no resultado de busca, mesmo elas não existindo, o que leva ao usuário uma péssima experiência pois não há nada.

Vejam: [O RESULTADO Link da pesquisa no Google com site:meusite.com.br ainda com as tags](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:ramosdainformatica.com.br&ei=rrQ3XdbgN5SG0Aa10rWACw&start=50&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjW74eGtMzjAhUUA9QKHTVpDbA4KBDy0wMIhQE&biw=1440&bih=757)

Como posso fazer o Google não indexar as "Tags" que, já não existem mais?

PS: Já deu tempo de reindexar e ler o XML, que fazem 4 semanas que removi todas as tags.

Comment: Neste link você obtém mais informações sobre sitemap.
https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/sitemap-xml/ Você deve ajustar para que impeça a indexação, redirecione e liste os novos endereços. No Google Search Console (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) você pode verificar e solicitar nova indexação.

Comment: Cara acho que isso pode te ajudar, ou pelo menos te dar uma luz... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266584/o-google-leva-mais-em-considera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-o-nome-de-view-controller-ou-parametros/266608#266608 de qq forma o Google pode demorar semanas até parar de indexar rotas inexistentes ou mesmo atualizar um conteúdo mostrado na SERP sobre isso talvez essa outra resposta possa te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383314/indexa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-google-tag-h1/383322#383322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar, a resposta foi criar um bloqueio via bot.

1. Criei um arquivo Robots.txt com:

   Disallow: /tag/
2. Enviei este arquivo para a raiz do site.
3. No Console do Google pedi para reindexar o site.

Pronto. Já não mostra as tags.

PS: Lendo a documentação do Google, há o resultado "Pagina 1 -", "Pagina 2 -", mas eles não recomendam bloquear a indexação de "/page/" pois atrapalha a indexação, então isso não é problema.

Por usar o Ubbersugest do Neil Patel, a ferramenta dele diz que é um problema, mas a documentação do Google diz que não deve proibir os "/page/" que pode atrapahar a indexação do site.